My particle is rotating constantly as I move curve
I want to create this rolling velcro effect, I'm using this spiral curve as a guiding object for my velcro to roll. But the problem is that my particle is constantly rotating in a wave motion as i move the curve (but when i move the velcro to the side the particle doesn't constantly rotate).
I have tried parent the curve to a new empty but nothing works. Is there any solution for this problem?
Blender version 4.0
